# T-SQL - WHERE Clause to find enters where date is next week but also in current quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

I have a simple table structure containing tasks assigned to resources:

`| TASK | START_DATE              | RESOURCE | CLOSED |`

`| T1   | 2018-10-10 00:00:00.000 | Bill     | 0      |`

`| T2   | 2018-11-12 00:00:00.000 | Bob      | 0      |`

`| T3   | 2018-11-17 00:00:00.000 | Ben      | 0      |`

I have a report that is intended to show the tasks that need to be completed next week and my current filter is:

`WHERE CLOSED = 0 AND ((DATEPART(wk,Tasks.Start_Date) -1) = DATEPART(wk,getutcdate()) and DATEPART(YY,Tasks.Start_Date) = DATEPART(yy,getutcdate()))`

The filter works perfectly when the task has a start date that is in the next week but I also have tasks that run quarterly which are being excluded by this filter.

Is there a way to build a filter that includes all tasks for this quarter as well as the tasks for next week? For example the Task identified as T1 is still open despite having a start date in the past (2018-10-10 00:00:00.000) I still need it to show on my report.

Thanks!

Comment: what technology are you using?  MS, My, oracle, other SQL?

Comment: Database engine is MS SQL sorry

Comment: The general check for overlapping ranges is `Start1 <= End2 and Start2 <= End1`. Refer to the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag wiki for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using MSSQL, you can use the simplified conditions below to provide increased readability..:

```
WHERE CLOSED = 0 
  AND Tasks.Start_Date < DATEADD(WEEK,1,GETDATE())
```

EDIT: If it is required to get the tasks will start in next week and started in this quarter only, since the where clause above brings all the tasks that already started and having CLOSED=0, use below:

```
WHERE CLOSED = 0 
  AND Tasks.Start_Date < DATEADD(WEEK,1,GETDATE())
  AND YEAR(Tasks.Start_Date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
  AND DATEPART(QUARTER, Tasks.Start_Date)=DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE())
```

Comment: *that includes all tasks for this quarter as well as the tasks for next week* means you need another predicate so you don't get **every** previous record unless `closed = 0` is only the current quarter records.

Comment: @scsimon so you think the where clause in my answer does not cover the tasks already started and will start in next week?

Comment: Yes it covers that, but OP stated next week and this quarter. Your code would pull all previous quarters unless the `closed` column is only = 0 for the *current* quarter. They'd need to clarify this.

Comment: @scsimon ah, got you. Updated my answer. Nice catch, thanks for sharing with me.

Comment: This is interesting but is still returning way more data that I am looking... for example I'm getting data back from 2017. How about if I added an end date to my record set and knew the start and end date could I then say find all tasks for next week that fall in the current quarter?

Comment: @andrew.reynolds81 could you please add YEAR(Tasks.Start_Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) as a condition and try again?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - I think that got it! I will test a little more but the initial pull looks great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

So if closed is = 0 and it is in the past?  You can do an OR statement:

```
WHERE CLOSED = 0 
AND (
    ((DATEPART(wk,Tasks.Start_Date) -1) = DATEPART(wk,getutcdate()) and DATEPART(YY,Tasks.Start_Date) = DATEPART(yy,getutcdate()))
    OR
    Tasks.Start_Date <= GetDate()  -- if using MS SQL
)
```

This will return everything you already were but also where closed = 0 and the StartDate is in the past.